# MongoInvalidArgumentError: URI option "w" cannot appear more than once in the connection string issue

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mern

I'm kinda new to programming, and I'm following a tutorial, but I'm stuck on getting Mongo to work, can someone help me out, I keep getting the same error in the terminal.  MongoServerError: bad auth: authentication failed

//server.ts

```
import "dotenv/config";
import env from"./util/validateEnv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";

const app = express();
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Hello, World!");
  });



const port = env.PORT;

mongoose.connect(env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING!)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Mongoose connected");
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log("Server running on port: " + port);
    });
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

//.env

```
MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb+srv://zambini:<password>@cluster0.luklrab.mongodb.net/
PORT=5000
```

// valiadateEnv.ts

```
import { cleanEnv } from "envalid";
import { port, str } from "envalid/dist/validators";

export default cleanEnv(process.env, {
    MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING: str(),
    PORT: port(),
});
```

Comment: You have a `!` at the end of your connection string here `mongoose.connect(env.MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING!)`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: looks like you have to double check your connection string, what you show doesn't look like used

Comment: I forgot to remove the !, although now I have a new error message saying MongoServerError: bad auth : authentication failed
    at Connection.onMessage . And how would I double-check that connection? What method would I use?

Comment: then it's a different error, check your credentials. Also, check this configuration: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/setup-cluster-security/#add-ip-addresses-to-the-whitelist